# Opinions on Stand Mounted Baffles (and LDCs)?

Tags: recommendations, recording, room-treatment, baffling, microphone

So I'm in the market for an affordable LDC for some vocal design work at home. My first thought was Røde's [NT2000](http://www.rodemic.com/microphone.php?product=NT2000). As it turns out, during the month of August Røde has a promotion wherein you buy a select LDC and they throw in a [Vicoustic Flexi Screen Lite](https://www.rodemic.com/vicoustic_registration.php) for an extra $1.

Now a while back I had seen sE's [Reflexion Filter](http://www.seelectronics.com/PSRF.html) and thought it was cool, but questioned its complete effectiveness. This Vicoustic product doesn't appear to be as thoroughly thought out (but for a buck does it really need to be?). My real question I guess is whether they are worth the space to store, or if should I just use blankets in my coat closet? Does anyone have experience with either of these products?

Also, because I don't want to spend $600 on the merit of a promotion (of a product I may not need), I'll take alternative thoughts on the LDC. I'm hoping to shell out no more than $700, but may be able to persuade the 'accountant' with something like the [MJE-K47H](http://www.oktavamodshop.com/product_info.php?cPath=2_28&products_id=144) and an Oktava or MXL body. *"But Honey, this is **expandable**. So it's like I'm actually buying multiple mics!"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My opinion on this matter is that treating your room properly from the ground up is the only way to get excellent quality recordings. The "quick fix" contraptions never really get there for me. Good luck reading a script with that foam box you put behind the mic, too. I guess they made that for the singers who memorize their lyrics? You have to fix the room itself for voices to sound good in a recording.

That's my opinion... Don't know if you have the space/time/budget for it...

Comment: But @Ryan, That's what this apparatus is for: http://bit.ly/cba1uY LOL! I'm all about doing it right, but unfortunately space/time/budget don't allow for a full room correction. I'm just wondering if these types of things are functional at all.

Comment: @Steve And I answered you. I do not think they are functional... It's going to sound amateur. The cheapest workable portable room handling I know of costs 350$ a piece and you need at least 8 of them for it to sound good, so I think it's a bit out of your budget.

Comment: @Steve Plus, that sE reflection stand doesn't look like it allows you to place the mic upside-down to the talent. Do you think you'll have trouble with it? If it works for you, then it works for you. But, in my experience, the auralex and foam quickie fixes have never totally eliminated room tone and I've used many of them, trust me.